# How to Show the X,Y co-ords upon click and show in console

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been learning c++ for over two weeks now and I'm trying to put what knowledge I have to practice by writing a simple console application that shows the X & Y co-ordinates of my mouse cursor, I have looked at the MSDN Libs and tried making sense, but all I have managed to do is show the co-ords but in the wrong way.

Here is the code I have now, it's not a lot but I want to make sure I'm doing things in the right way so I don't pick up bad habits;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() 
{
POINT cursorPos;
GetCursorPos(&cursorPos);
printf("X %d    Y %d\n", cursorPos.x, cursorPos.y);


system("PAUSE");
}
```

The main goal of this is to have the console open (once run) and listening for left clicks and then displaying that Co-ord in the console until its clicked again!

Any help on this would be much appreciated, and sorry if this has been posted somewhere before I have tried searching but had no luck!

Regards

Chris

Comment: There are two ways to write a Windows program: as a console application, and as a windowed application. You have a console app here, and console apps are very limited in how they can interact with a mouse. I'd advise learning how to do a windowed app.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() 
{
    POINT cursorPos;

    do
    {
        GetCursorPos( &cursorPos );
        printf("X %d    Y %d\n", cursorPos.x, cursorPos.y);
        Sleep( 100 );
    }
    while ( cursorPos.x != 0 || cursorPos.y != 0 );

    // just "for fun", as an example,
    // you have to set your mouse to X=0, Y=0 to exit!

    return 0;
}
```

The thing is: a program is just a sequence of operations, so **"if it finishes what it does... it dies!"**

When a program stays alive, it means it is actually running in a "event-loop". It means a loop that "keeps the program alive". It has many names depending on the system/platform you are working on (like, in OS X, it's called RunLoops, for example), but it's all the same idea.

The basic and general idea of this "event loop" is basically always the same thing: watch for user input, watch for system input, and do some action according to the inputs (many times, the action is just "sleep!")

With this method. Your program will always keep alive! UNTIL it responds to a input that that means "close it". (For example, in Windows, it may be WM_QUIT messages when you are working with windows, or just a ESC key, in a console mode, etc...)

IS THIS EXAMPLE ABOVE, I just gave "as example" to quit if the mouse position goes to `(x=0, y=0)`.

Comment: Thanks, I had this running in a while(1) loop before, I think I need to look into windowed apps for me to use the clicking side of things, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use the consoles own event handler for keyboard and mouse -  `ReadConsoleInput( )`

Read more here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685035(v=vs.85).aspx

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void setcolor(WORD color);
void setForeGroundAndBackGroundColor(int ForeGroundColor,int BackGroundColor);
void clearscreen();
void drawpixel( unsigned char x, unsigned char y, unsigned char Color);
void drawpixel2( unsigned char x, unsigned char y, unsigned char Color, char character);
void drawcircle(int x, int y, int a, int b, int color);
void drawline(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int color);
void drawfilledrectangle(unsigned char x1,unsigned char y1,unsigned char x2,unsigned char y2,unsigned char bkcol);
void drawframe(unsigned x,unsigned y,unsigned sx,unsigned sy,unsigned char col,unsigned char col2,char text_[]);
void drawwindow(unsigned x,unsigned y,unsigned sx,unsigned sy,unsigned char col,unsigned char col2,unsigned char bkcol,char text_[]);

int main()
{
    gotoxy(1,23);
    setcolor(7);
    clearscreen();

    cout<<"click anywhere in console window to write - hello world -\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
    "Press Ctrl+C to Exit";

        HANDLE hout= GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        HANDLE hin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        INPUT_RECORD InputRecord;
        DWORD Events;
        COORD coord;
        CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
        cci.dwSize = 25;
        cci.bVisible = FALSE;
        SetConsoleCursorInfo(hout, &cci);
        SetConsoleMode(hin, ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT);
        bool EXITGAME = false;
        int buttonX=1, buttonY=1;

        drawpixel(buttonX,buttonY ,1);
        gotoxy(buttonX+2,buttonY);
        setcolor(3);
        cout<<"<----- a button \n";


    while( !EXITGAME )
    {

        ReadConsoleInput(hin, &InputRecord, 1, &Events);


        switch ( InputRecord.EventType ){
                case KEY_EVENT: // keyboard input 


                    switch (InputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode)
                    {
                        case VK_ESCAPE:
                           EXITGAME = TRUE;
                         break;

                        case VK_SPACE:

                         break;


                        case VK_RETURN:

                         break;

                        case VK_LEFT:
                            // left key   move player left
                            cout<<"VK_LEFT   = "<<InputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode <<" \n";

                         break;

                        case VK_RIGHT:
                            // right key   move player right
                            cout<<"VK_RIGHT   = "<<InputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode <<" \n";

                         break;

                        case VK_UP:
                            // up key   move player up
                            cout<<"VK_UP   = "<<InputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode <<" \n";


                         break;

                        case VK_DOWN:
                            // up key   move player down
                            cout<<"VK_DOWN   = "<<InputRecord.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode <<" \n";


                         break;



                    }//switch

                    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                    break; 

                case MOUSE_EVENT: // mouse input 

                    if(InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState == FROM_LEFT_1ST_BUTTON_PRESSED)
                    {
                        coord.X = InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X;
                        coord.Y = InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y;
                        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hout,coord);
                        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hout,rand() %7+9);

                        if ( (InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X == buttonX ) && 
                            ( InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y == buttonY) ){

                            clearscreen();
                            gotoxy(1,1);
                            setcolor(7);
                            drawpixel(buttonX,buttonY ,1);
                            setcolor(3);
                            cout<<" mybutton was pressed \n";
                            setcolor(7);
                            Sleep(500);
                            drawpixel(buttonX,buttonY ,1);
                            gotoxy(buttonX+2,buttonY);
                            setcolor(3);
                            cout<<"<----- a button      \n";


                        }

                        cout<<"Hello world at "<< InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X <<" x "<< InputRecord.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y<<" ";

                    }// mouse 

                    break; 

                case WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT: // scrn buf. resizing 
                     ; 
                    break; 

                case FOCUS_EVENT:  // disregard focus events 

                case MENU_EVENT:   // disregard menu events 

                    break; 

                default: 
                    cout<<"Unknown event type \n"; 
                    break; 
        }



        FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hin);
    }
    gotoxy(1,23);
    setcolor(7);
    clearscreen();
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;

}



void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
    return;
}

//*****************************************************************************

void setcolor(WORD color){
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),color);
    return;
}

//*****************************************************************************


//
//     colors:
//     0 = Black
//     1 = Blue
//     2 = Green
//     3 = Cyan
//     4 = Red
//     5 = Magenta
//     6 = Yellow
//     7 = LightGray
//     8 = DarkGray
//     9 = LightBlue
//     10 = LightGreen
//     11 = LightCyan
//     12 = LightRed
//     13 = LightMagenta
//     14 = LightYellow
//     15 = White


//

//*****************************************************************************

void setForeGroundAndBackGroundColor(int ForeGroundColor,int BackGroundColor){
   int color=16*BackGroundColor+ForeGroundColor;
   setcolor(color);
}

//*****************************************************************************

void clearscreen(){
    COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };
    DWORD cCharsWritten;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    DWORD dwConSize;
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
    dwConSize = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, TEXT(' '), dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hConsole, csbi.wAttributes, dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coordScreen);
    return;
}

//*****************************************************************************

void drawpixel( unsigned char x, unsigned char y, unsigned char Color){
        setcolor(Color);
        gotoxy(x,y);printf("Û");
}
//*****************************************************************************

void drawpixel2( unsigned char x, unsigned char y, unsigned char Color, char character){
        setcolor(Color);
        gotoxy(x,y);printf("%c",character);
}

//*****************************************************************************

void drawcircle(int x, int y, int a, int b, int color){
    int wx, wy;
    int thresh;
    int asq = a * a;
    int bsq = b * b;
    int xa, ya;

    drawpixel(x, y+b, color);
    drawpixel(x, y-b, color);

    wx = 0;
    wy = b;
    xa = 0;
    ya = asq * 2 * b;
    thresh = asq / 4 - asq * b;

    for (;;) {
        thresh += xa + bsq;

        if (thresh >= 0) {
            ya -= asq * 2;
            thresh -= ya;
            wy--;
        }

        xa += bsq * 2;
        wx++;

        if (xa >= ya)
          break;


        drawpixel(x+wx, y-wy, color);
        drawpixel(x-wx, y-wy, color);
        drawpixel(x+wx, y+wy, color);
        drawpixel(x-wx, y+wy, color);
    }

    drawpixel(x+a, y, color);
    drawpixel(x-a, y, color);

    wx = a;
    wy = 0;
    xa = bsq * 2 * a;

    ya = 0;
    thresh = bsq / 4 - bsq * a;

    for (;;) {
        thresh += ya + asq;

        if (thresh >= 0) {
            xa -= bsq * 2;
            thresh = thresh - xa;
            wx--;
        }

        ya += asq * 2;
        wy++;

        if (ya > xa)
          break;

        drawpixel(x+wx, y-wy, color);
        drawpixel(x-wx, y-wy, color);
        drawpixel(x+wx, y+wy, color);
        drawpixel(x-wx, y+wy, color);
    }
}

//*****************************************************************************

void drawline(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int color){
    int pix = color;
    int dy = y1 - y0;
    int dx = x1 - x0;
    int stepx, stepy;

    if (dy < 0) { dy = -dy;  stepy = -1; } else { stepy = 1; }
    if (dx < 0) { dx = -dx;  stepx = -1; } else { stepx = 1; }
    dy <<= 1;                                                  // dy is now 2*dy
    dx <<= 1;                                                  // dx is now 2*dx

  drawpixel( x0, y0,pix);
    if (dx > dy) {
        int fraction = dy - (dx >> 1);                         // same as 2*dy - dx
        while (x0 != x1) {
            if (fraction >= 0) {
                y0 += stepy;
                fraction -= dx;                                // same as fraction -= 2*dx
            }
            x0 += stepx;
            fraction += dy;                                    // same as fraction -= 2*dy
            drawpixel( x0, y0,pix);
        }
    } else {
        int fraction = dx - (dy >> 1);
        while (y0 != y1) {
            if (fraction >= 0) {
                x0 += stepx;
                fraction -= dy;
            }
            y0 += stepy;
            fraction += dx;
            drawpixel( x0, y0,pix);
        }
    }
}

//*****************************************************************************


void drawframe(unsigned x,unsigned y,unsigned sx,unsigned sy,unsigned char col,unsigned char col2,char text_[]){
    unsigned i,j,m;{

       m=(sx-x);                       //differential
       j=m/8;                          //adjust
       j=j-1;                          //more adjustment
       gotoxy(x,y);printf("É");       //Top left corner of drawframe
       gotoxy(sx,y);printf("»");      //Top right corner of drawframe
       gotoxy(x,sy);printf("È");      //Bottom left corner of drawframe
       gotoxy(sx,sy);printf("¼");     //Bottom right corner of drawframe

       for (i=x+1;i<sx;i++){
          gotoxy(i,y);printf("Í");     // Top horizontol line
          gotoxy(i,sy);printf("Í");    // Bottom Horizontal line
       }

       for (i=y+1;i<sy;i++){
          gotoxy(x,i);printf("º");     //Left Vertical line
          gotoxy(sx,i);printf("º");    //Right Vertical Line
       }

          gotoxy(x+j,y);printf(text_); //put Title
          gotoxy(1,24);
    }
}

 //*****************************************************************************

void drawfilledrectangle(unsigned char x1,unsigned char y1,unsigned char x2,unsigned char y2,unsigned char bkcol){
    int x,y;
    setcolor(bkcol);                       //Set to color bkcol

    for (y=y1;y<y2;y++){                    //Fill Y Region Loop
        for (x=x1;x<x2;x++) {              //Fill X region Loop
          gotoxy(x,y);printf(" ");       //Draw Solid space
        }
    }
}

//*****************************************************************************

void drawwindow(unsigned x,unsigned y,unsigned sx,unsigned sy,
         unsigned char col, unsigned char col2,unsigned char bkcol,char text_[]){
    drawfilledrectangle(x,y,sx,sy,bkcol);
    drawframe(x,y,sx,sy,col,col2,text_);
}

//*****************************************************************************


void drawcolorpalette(){
    for (int i=0;i<16;i++){
        for (int j=0;j<16;j++){
            setForeGroundAndBackGroundColor(i,j);
            gotoxy(i*4,j);printf("%d",(i*j)+1);


        }

    }

}


//*****************************************************************************
```